# Ionic 2: Register custom typings file in RC.0

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2, typescript-typings

In beta11 I put my own customTypings.d.ts in the typings folder.
This folder doesn't exist in Ionic RC.0.

**Q) So how do I register my custom typings file now in RC.0?**

*e.g. customTypings.d.ts:*

```
interface Window {
    plugins: any;
}

declare var SignaturePad: {
    new(canvas: any, options?: any): any;
}

interface CordovaPlugins {
    OneSignal: any;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

- Make a custom folder in the `src` directory e.g. `customTypings`
- Shove your custom typings in a file in that directory e.g. `customTypings.d.ts`.

Then they'll be included in the compile.

DONE.

Comment: This does not work for me. The `customTypings.d.ts` are not found. When I try reference them, it looks at `src/declarations.d.ts` and not `customTypings.d.ts`.